# При (не)подписании протокола?

Tags: правописание

Добрый день уважаемые знатоки русской речи!
Остро встал вопрос в организации на тему написания данного словосочетания.
Позиции и объяснения у всех разные.

Прошу Вас дайте пожалуйста ответ - слитно или раздельно следует писать "(не)подписание" в данном сочетании. И если можете дайте небольшие комментарии.

Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

**Слитно**: нет противопоставления с союзом А, слово можно заменить синонимом без НЕ или близким по значению выражением.

Answer (score 3):

Конечно, слитно. Приставка НЕ образует новое слово с противоположным значением: подписание - неподписание.  У Екатерины - способ проверки.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь только слитное написание, и дело даже не в замене синонимом (который, кстати, трудно подобрать). Замена синонимом делается для проверки утвердительного характера синтаксической конструкции, а здесь конструкция именно утвердительная - это падежная форма существительного "неподписание" (которое имеется в словаре). Частица "НЕ" НЕ МОЖЕТ НАХОДИТЬСЯ между предлогом и существительным.